# Regex: How to match all numbers just not one?

Tags: regex

This should be so easy to do however I have been searching online and trying different patterns on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ with no success!

I need to match all numbers and numbers only (from the beginning) except 1 or anything starting with a leading 0 so these would match

```
2
222
1234567
```

and these would not:

```
01
1
someword
```

Your help would be much appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: Which expressions have you tried?

Comment: You can also use http://rubular.com/ for testing.

Comment: You commented on an answer that you already tried `([2-9]\d*)` and it didn't work as desired. That's the reason why you should post your attempts, so that others don't waste their and your time proposing the same.

Comment: `(?<!\d)([1-9]\d+|[2-9])`

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you for your constructive comment and suggestion, from now on I will make sure to post all my attempts, Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(\b(([2-9]\d*)|(1\d+)))
```

[Test case](http://regexr.com?37th4).

Comment: This is exactly what I had, and like mentioned it will not match 1234567, Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Apologies, that was kinda unclear, fixed it. See test case, think it matches all your requirements right now including word boundaries, mid of text matching etc.

Comment: I didn't see what it was before but what it is now works for me.

Comment: I had misinterpreted the requirement that `1` was not allowed but `123` was.

Answer (score 3):

`^((?:[2-9][0-9]*)|(?:1[0-9]+))$`

would work, Spiting each case

Example
http://regex101.com/r/wW9jQ7

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly! (Will however accept the highest voted comment and the oldest one!), Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way with no negation and no lookarounds:

```
^([2-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]+)$
```

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/xZ2zC5

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, will accept shortly! Thanks again.

Comment: This matches `0` as well. Not sure if it it should or shouldn't.

Comment: @FelixKling indeed -- but user1995272 didn't indicate whether that should be in the criteria? That would require: `(^[1-9]+$|^[^10]$)`, which is actually simpler.

Comment: Alternatively, ^([02-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)$ which avoids negation.  I think both expressions work.

Comment: That matches "a12345"

Comment: Ah Felix you're right, I did not notice that, Can I exclude it just like the 1 is excluded? something like (^[^0][1-9]+$|^[^1|0]$)?

Comment: It also matches any single character expect `1`. E.g. `f`.

Comment: `(^[^0][1-9]+$|^[^10\w]$)` negates letters as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is about the shortest I can think of:

```
^(?!1$)[^0]\d*$
```

Comment: Might be shortest, but the look-ahead will impact performance.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes it's a pretty small look ahead, and fixed length. I doubt it will make a noticeable difference. Besides, I like terse code :)

Comment: I'm just saying short isn't always better  :)  If a regexp doesn't need lookaheads/behinds/arounds, usually best to avoid them. We don't know if the OP wants to run it 10000 times per second  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Single digits are special, so:

```
(^[2-9]$|^[1-9][0-9]+$)
```